# Can't apply windows firewall for VPN with Vivaldi browser

Tags: windows, vpn, firewall

Im using SoftEther VPN with Windows 7 on a VM.

I'd like to block all connections if my VPN loses connection to protect my ip from leaking. The simplest way to do this is to create a windows firewall rule to block incoming / outcoming traffic for your browser for PRIVATE and DOMAIN connections but not public. You'd set your VPN connection to PUBLIC and if the VPN disconnects Windows switches to your local connection which is PRIVATE and is blocked.

Source: http://www.24vc.com/guide?v=how-to-block-non-vpn-traffic

Vivaldi does not appear to have a normal installation folder like other browsers but I found its .exe here: user\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe and used this as the program destination to block with the windows firewall.

When I disconnect the VPN the windows firewall does not appear to block Vivaldi. Other browsers are blocked as expected.

Any ideas why Vivaldi is not being blocked? Is there a source folder I am not seeing?